# Oracle: Composite unique key with Date column

Tags: oracle11g, unique-constraint

I have created a table with composite unique key as below--

```
create table test11 
(
     aa number, 
     bb varchar2(10),
     cc DATE, 
     dd number,
     ee NUMBER
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST11_IDX ON TEST11 (AA,BB,CC);
```

Now, whenever I try to insert data, I get this error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (CDUREFDB.TEST11_IDX) violated

```
INSERT INTO TEST11 VALUES (1, 'AA', SYSDATE, 1, 1);
commit;

INSERT INTO TEST11 VALUES (1, 'AA', SYSDATE, 1, 1);
commit;
```

Is that because of `DATE` column is considering `Date` value till seconds?
Because I could see below query is returning is result--

```
select to_char(CC,'DD-Mon-YY HH:Mi:SS AM') from test11;

TO_CHAR(CC,'DD-MON-YYHH:MI:SSAM')
---------------------------------
17-Mar-16 04:28:37 PM             
17-Mar-16 04:28:43 PM
```

So, what can be done in order to only consider Date value (not hours, mins, secs precision) as unique key member.

Also, `DATE` column above(CC) has partition on it.

**UPDATE:**:

In this table, we have RANGE partition on DATE column(CC).

And we are planning to remove partitions periodically (i.e. after some days interval).

So if I Don't use direct CC in unique index ( instead of making trunc as Justin suggested) then i am getting error as `ORA-01502: index 'CDUREFDB.TEST111_IDX' or partition of such index is in unusable state` if I try to insert data after some old partition got removed .

**UPDATE_1**
As per @Justin suggestion below, this issue is resolved creating virtual column like below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST11
  (
    AA NUMBER,
    BB VARCHAR2(10),
    CC DATE,
    DD NUMBER ,
    EE NUMBER,
    FF DATE generated always AS (TRUNC(CC)) virtual
  )
  PARTITION BY RANGE
  (
    FF
  )
  INTERVAL
  (
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')
  )
  (
    PARTITION partition_test_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2006','dd-MON-yyyy'))
  );



CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST111_IDX ON TEST11 (AA,BB,FF) LOCAL;  -- creating unique local index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `date` always has a time component so your two rows have different `cc` values.  You could create a function-based index based on the `trunc(cc)` value which will set the time component to midnight.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST11_IDX 
    ON TEST11 (AA,BB,trunc(CC));
```

Of course, that means that if you want a query to use the index, you'd want to ensure that your predicate is on `trunc(cc)` rather than `cc`.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. So there is no impact of having partition on that column? Because we will be periodically removing data from this table based on `range partition` which we will be imposing on DATE column.

Comment: @AshishPatil - I generally wouldn't be crazy about having global indexes on a partitioned table but you have that with either the index you initially created or the function-based index.  I'd expect that either would need to be rebuilt after partitions are dropped.  Now, if your actual index was a local index (which I would expect would require that `cc` be the leading column), then you have a rather different question.  In that case, it might make sense to add a virtual column on `trunc(cc)` and partition the table by that.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave again.  I have made DATE column as virtual and now able to remove partition as well as I am able to make sure to use only DATE as member in composition of unique key.